# XSD: Index of sequence in Element name

Tags: java, xsd

I'm building an XSD to generate JAXB objects in Java.  Then I ran into this:

```
<TotalBugs>
<Bug1>...</Bug1>
<Bug2>...</Bug2>
...
<BugN>...</BugN>
</TotalBugs>
```

How do I build a sequence of elements where the index of the sequence is in the element name? Specifically, how do I get the 1 in Bug1

Comment: Can't your schema just have multiple `<bug>` elements?

Comment: Indeed it can, the trick is that the xml that I'm required to build has these silly little indexes next to the Bug name. I couldn't tell you why, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do it in this way, XML has a top-down order by nature. Consequently, you don't have to enumerate yourself:

```
<totalBugs>
<bug><!-- Here comes 1st bug --></bug>
<bug><!-- Here comes 2nd bug --></bug>
...
<bug><!-- Here comes last bug --></bug>
</totalBugs>
```

You can access the 1st bug node in the list by the XPath expression:

```
/totalBugs/bug[1]
```

Note, indexes start by W3C standard at 1. Please refer to for further readings to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp).

Comment: I know I don't want to do it this way, but I don't have a choice. This is the xml that I need to turn into an xsd. Is this even possible

Comment: Ok, I understand. It seems the best way to first parse the XML file or XML String contents and eliminate the Bug1, Bug2, ... and bring it into the above plain structure. You can use regex to do it, String xml="<TotalBugs><Bug1>...<Bugn>..</Bugn></TotalBugs>"; xml = xml.replaceAll("<Bug\\d+>","Bug"); - or you can parse a file linewise using BufferedReader and process the XML linewise.

I think there is no way to define an XSD for your original XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure XSD won't support what you need. However you can use `<xsd:any>` for that bit of the schema, then use something lower-level than JAXB to generate the XML for that particular part. (I think your generated classes will have fields like `protected List<Element> any;` which you can fill in using DOM).